# How to maintain Windows 10 modern volume control UI when mouse wheel is used?

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer

When I click the speaker icon in the Windows 10 task bar, the new volume control appears. If I change the volume by scrolling the middle mouse button, the volume control reverts to the old volume control. It's quite jarring.

If I use the <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> keys the volume is changed without reverting to the old volume control.

Two questions:

- Is this the standard behavior? (I tried switching to the old volume controls and switching back to the modern controls using the registry scripts from [How to Get the Old Volume Control Back on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/323371/how-to-get-the-old-volume-control-back-on-windows-10/).)
- How can I maintain the modern UI when changing volume with the mouse wheel?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Perhaps some installed application is causing it?

Comment: Came here to say the same as harrymc. I can't reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments that this is not standard behavior, I tried disabling some background programs. The culprit was [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)!

I totally forgot about one of its features:

- Control volume when mouse is over the notification area.

After I disabled this setting, the old volume control does not appear. This is actually a handy feature, so I changed it to activate when over "the taskbar."

---

A [feature request/bug](https://tweaker.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/611-use-new-volume-slider-aesthetic-fixupgrade) was actually opened for this issue, and it was updated/fixed in 7+ Taskbar Tweaker v5.6.2.3.